# primitives for detecting typesetting direction in pdftex and xetex?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, e-tex

Probably a duplicate, but...

...are there primitives for *detecting* the current typesetting direction in the said e-TeX based engines?

I know that setting `\TeXXeTstate` > 0 enables `\beginR, \beginL, \endR, \endL` for *setting* the direction, and that pkg `bidi` provides conditionals for that purpose. However `bidi` cannot be used with `pdftex`.

Comment: My advise would be 'do not do this': the TeX--XeT model has various issues! Is there a reason you can't simply box up your material inside a 'known pair'?

Comment: I would like to make some of my packages on CTAN aware of the current typesetting direction (with any engine).

Comment: Note that the `bidi` approach  for this 'core' task would work in pdfTeX: it's a construct around the primitives with a flag set. However, quite a lot of work by the LaTeX team suggests at least to me that TeX--XeT is flawed: I really would be cautious here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this as, unlike the omega/luatex model, direction is not a property of the typeset list (box) there are just nodes that change the direction state when encountered.

this means that the direction may not be known at the time the tex macros are executed, in fact the same text may be set in either direction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newbox\foo

\TeXXeTstate=1

\begin{document}

\sbox\foo{hello world}

\beginR \usebox\foo \endR

\usebox\foo

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

`hello world` here is just simple text but it could be arbitrarily complex macros testing any conditionals, none of which would be re-executed when the text is displayed in the other direction.

Comment: I guess in a real application one therefore would expect a higher-level box implementation to add the appropriate 'wrapper' nodes, but then one can also have a flag to indicate the state (which is what `bidi` does).

Comment: Well this was surprising. I wouldn't have expected the box to change like this. What about kerning here? I mean "Fo" has a different to "oF"  doesn't that means that dimension can be wrong?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's kerned as Fo basically it just flips the order of the final list just at the last moment while writing the dvi

Comment: This doesn't sound sane from a typografical viewpoint. And I just tried with FoFoFoFoFoFoFoFoFoFoFoFoFoFo and it looks odd also without boxes. What should one do to get correct output?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer use Word?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if you were using a font intended for RTL typesetting then hopefully the kerning pairs would be set up correctly for that direction, typesetting latin characters backwards isn't really a design aim of tex-(-)xet

Comment: Hm yes. That's an argument. So no mirror puzzles with tex--xet or only with typewriter fonts ...